# What is wrong with my Enumeration?

Tags: java, enumeration

I am following the book and there is an example of enumeration. So I am doing this:

```
  enum Color {
    GREEN("GREEN"),
    YELLOW("YELLOW"),
    RED("RED");

   String name;

   Color(String name) {
     this.name = name;
     }

   public String getColor() {
        return name;
     }


 }
```

and then I want to create Objects and return the color through my class like this:

```
class TrafficLight extends enum<Color> {   // I am getting an error:
                                           //  Classes cannot directly extend java.lang.Enum

// ...create objects and etc.


}
```

How can I fix this error? Because this is exactly the same syntax from my book and do not know how to make it correct.

EDIT: my book syntax:

```
enum Suit {
CLUBS("CLUBS"),
DIAMONDS("DIAMONDS"),
HEARTS("HEARTS"),
SPADES("SPADES");
String name;
Suit(String name) { this.name = name; }
public String toString() { return name; }
}

class Suit extends Enum<Suit> // pseudo-code only
implements Comparable<Suit>, Serializable {
public static final Suit CLUBS = new Suit("CLUBS");
public static final Suit DIAMONDS = new Suit("DIAMONDS");
public static final Suit HEARTS = new Suit("HEARTS");
public static final Suit SPADES = new Suit("SPADES");
String name;
Suit(String name) { this.name = name; }
public String toString() { return name; }
// ... compiler generated methods ...
}
```

Comment: You sure it's a Java book?

Comment: Indeed enums cannot be extended.

Comment: THE Java™ Programming Language, Fourth Edition
By Ken Arnold, James Gosling, David Holmes. Yes. I am sure...

Comment: @Ernusc: That seems really hard to believe, not least because `enum<Color>` is trying to use a reserved word (`enum`) where you want the built-in type `Enum`.

Comment: 145 page. I added syntax from my book.

Answer (score 1):

Look carefully.

- Compare this:

  ```
  class TrafficLight extends enum<Color>
  ```

  with this

  ```
  class Suit extends Enum<Suit>
  ```

  Java is case-sensitive. `Enum<Color>` and `enum<Color>` are very different. (The latter is simply not allowed.)
- In your example, you're trying to create one enum type which uses a different enum for the type argument (`TrafficLight` and `Color`). In the sample code, the enum type uses the *same* enum type (`Suit`) for both the declaration and the type argument.
- Did you spot this?

  ```
  // pseudo-code only
  ```

  You shouldn't *expect* pseudo-code to compile.

Answer (score 0):

Oh! Its just because that Classes cannot directly extend java.lang.Enum.

Answer (score 0):

Enums cannot be extended, as states the message you get.

If you want to return a Color, just create some method, which return type will be your enum `Color`.

Answer (score 0):

From your book :

> You can get a feel for how an enum is internally defined from the
>   following **pseudo-code**, which shows a mock class definition for the
>   above Suit enum

This is just to show you how an Enum is internally defined.

From the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) :

> The enum declaration defines a class (called an enum type). The enum
>   class body can include methods and other fields. The compiler
>   automatically adds some special methods when it creates an enum. For
>   example, they have a static values method that returns an array
>   containing all of the values of the enum in the order they are
>   declared.

Comment: Ahh, sorry I just checked the code, did not read that. Sorry guys

Answer (score 0):

> my book syntax:
>
> ...
>
> `class Suit extends Enum<Suit> // pseudo-code only`

Note the **pseudo-code only** comment. "Pseudo" means "not quite real." Pseudo-code is not real code and will not (usually) compile. I don't have the book, but presumably this code is to illustrate how things work behind the scenes, not literally code you can compile.

Comment: Thank you, I was not close enough. It helped to avoid a bad understanding about enumeration.

Answer (score 0):

The book is rather old (from 2005) so it might be a better starting point to use the [Oracle Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html). See the section here for [Enum Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

See an extended example of your Color enum class to print all values of the declared enums. (for more in deep explanation have a look at the Planet example in the tutorial)

```
enum Color {
    GREEN("green"),
    YELLOW("yellow"),
    RED("red");

    private final String name;

    Color(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return name;
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (Color color : Color.values()) {
            System.out.printf("enum class: %-6s  value: %s%n", color, color.getColor());
        }
    }
}
```